# Trying to get property of non-object laravel when accessing database

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to code the edit route for laravel and for some reason keep getting the error "Trying to get property of non-object laravel". The Create controller works fine, however when I use the controller@update route I keep getting this error

My Controller for adding an event: (update)

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
         //create event
         $my_user = my::find($id);
         $my_user->programme = $request->input('programme');
         $my_user->goal1 = $request->input('goal1');
         $my_user->goal2 = $request->input('goal2');
         $my_user->goal3 = $request->input('goal3');
         $my_user->goal4 = $request->input('goal4');
         $my_user->goal5 = $request->input('goal5');
         $my_user->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

         $my_user->save();

         return redirect('/home')->with('success','Event Created');
    }
```

edit page

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <h1>Edit Post</h1>
    {!! Form::open(['action' => ['myUserController@update', $my_user], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('title', 'Event Name')}}
            {{Form::text('goal1', $my_user->goal1, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Goal One'])}}

        </div>
        {{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
        {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}

</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Verify that you are actually retrieving the user in your  $my_user = my::find($id); You may try my::findOrFail($id); to see if anything comes out.

Comment: you have not returned `$my_user` variable to your view, this is the reason for your problem.

Comment: what is the output of dd($my_user) after $my_user = my::find($id); ???

Comment: @joem then you are not getting anything from your query. Use dd($id) to see if you are getting your $id passed in correctly. If not this may be a route problem with how you have defined the route name.

Comment: Please post the line of code in that is associated with defining this Route if possible.

Comment: @MattMcAlister        $user = User::find($id);
        dd($id); gives a blank page too when I add it to  public function edit($id)

Comment: Route::resource('myuser','UserController');

Comment: @joe m what is your controller method for viewing edit page???

Comment: @Sohel0415         $user = User::find($id);
        return($user_user);

Comment: @joe m have you tried dd($user) on your get method??

Comment: @joe m can you update your question and provide full implementation of your get and post method in controller file??

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using a Route::resource you can type-hint your parameters by writing something like

```
public function update(Request $request, MyUser $myuser){
    // The $myuser parameter comes from the Route::resource and can be verified using php artisan route:list in your terminal

    // edit $my_user
    $my_user->save();

    return redirect('/home')->with('success','Event Created');
}
```

**Update after reviewing LaravelCollective documentation for Form**

Thank you [Sohel0415](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4498691/sohel0415) for mentioning that you do not need to call $my_user->id for providing the route parameter with the Form facade.

Comment: using $my_user is correct in this context rather than $my_user->id

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method on your code:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/users/store' , 'method' =>'POST')) }}
```

and your route define by this method in web.php file:

```
Route::post('users/store', 'admin\UserController@store');
```